# Run the project on Android @ react-native 0.60.2, build success but nothing happens

Tags: react-native

one day I upgrade my react-native project from 0.59.3 to 0.60.2
set up AndroidX migration and run react-native run-android.
it shows Build successful, and the app installed on the simulator but metro bundler doesn't run

there are my settings:

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.60.2

here is the log on terminal

```sh
warn The following packages use deprecated "rnpm" config that will stop working from next release:
  - react-native-code-push: https://microsoft.github.io/code-push
Please notify their maintainers about it. You can find more details at https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#migration-guide.
error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually: 
  - @react-native-community/async-storage (to unlink run: "react-native unlink @react-native-community/async-storage")
  - react-native-amplitude-analytics (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-amplitude-analytics")
  - react-native-camera (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-camera")
  - react-native-code-push (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-code-push")
  - react-native-config (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-config")
  - react-native-firebase (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-firebase")
  - react-native-languages (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-languages")
  - react-native-os (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-os")
  - react-native-randombytes (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-randombytes")
  - react-native-splash-screen (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-splash-screen")
  - react-native-svg (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-svg")
  - react-native-tcp (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-tcp")
  - react-native-touch-id (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-touch-id")
  - react-native-udp (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-udp")
  - react-native-vector-icons (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-vector-icons")
  - react-native-version-number (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-version-number")
  - react-native-webview (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-webview")
This is likely happening when upgrading React Native from below 0.60 to 0.60 or above. Going forward, you can unlink this dependency via "react-native unlink <dependency>" and it will be included in your app automatically. If a library isn't compatible with autolinking, disregard this message and notify the library maintainers.
Read more about autolinking: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1351 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...

> Configure project :@react-native-community_async-storage
WARNING: The following project options are deprecated and have been removed: 
android.enableAapt2
This property has no effect, AAPT2 is now always used.


WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableD8.desugaring=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'.


> Configure project :app
WARNING: The following project options are deprecated and have been removed: 
android.enableAapt2
This property has no effect, AAPT2 is now always used.


WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableD8.desugaring=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'.

Reading env from: .env
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

> Configure project :react-native-amplitude-analytics
WARNING: The following project options are deprecated and have been removed: 
android.enableAapt2
This property has no effect, AAPT2 is now always used.


WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableD8.desugaring=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'.


> Configure project :react-native-camera
WARNING: The following project options are deprecated and have been removed: 
android.enableAapt2
This property has no effect, AAPT2 is now always used.


WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableD8.desugaring=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'.


> Configure project :react-native-code-push
WARNING: The following project options are deprecated and have been removed: 
android.enableAapt2
This property has no effect, AAPT2 is now always used.


WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableD8.desugaring=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'.


> Configure project :react-native-config
WARNING: The following project options are deprecated and have been removed: 
android.enableAapt2
This property has no effect, AAPT2 is now always used.


WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableD8.desugaring=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'.


> Configure project :react-native-firebase
WARNING: The following project options are deprecated and have been removed: 
android.enableAapt2
This property has no effect, AAPT2 is now always used.


WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableD8.desugaring=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'.

react-native-firebase: using React Native prebuilt binary from /Users/mac/Documents/GitHub/myrn/node_modules/react-native/android

> Configure project :react-native-keychain
WARNING: The following project options are deprecated and have been removed: 
android.enableAapt2
This property has no effect, AAPT2 is now always used.


WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableD8.desugaring=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'.


> Configure project :react-native-languages
WARNING: The following project options are deprecated and have been removed: 
android.enableAapt2
This property has no effect, AAPT2 is now always used.


WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableD8.desugaring=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'.


> Configure project :react-native-os
WARNING: The following project options are deprecated and have been removed: 
android.enableAapt2
This property has no effect, AAPT2 is now always used.


WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableD8.desugaring=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'.

WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

> Configure project :react-native-randombytes
WARNING: The following project options are deprecated and have been removed: 
android.enableAapt2
This property has no effect, AAPT2 is now always used.


WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableD8.desugaring=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'.


> Configure project :react-native-splash-screen
WARNING: The following project options are deprecated and have been removed: 
android.enableAapt2
This property has no effect, AAPT2 is now always used.


WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableD8.desugaring=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'.


> Configure project :react-native-svg
WARNING: The following project options are deprecated and have been removed: 
android.enableAapt2
This property has no effect, AAPT2 is now always used.


WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableD8.desugaring=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'.

WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

> Configure project :react-native-tcp
WARNING: The following project options are deprecated and have been removed: 
android.enableAapt2
This property has no effect, AAPT2 is now always used.


WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableD8.desugaring=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'.

WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

> Configure project :react-native-touch-id
WARNING: The following project options are deprecated and have been removed: 
android.enableAapt2
This property has no effect, AAPT2 is now always used.


WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableD8.desugaring=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'.


> Configure project :react-native-udp
WARNING: The following project options are deprecated and have been removed: 
android.enableAapt2
This property has no effect, AAPT2 is now always used.


WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableD8.desugaring=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'.

WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

> Configure project :react-native-vector-icons
WARNING: The following project options are deprecated and have been removed: 
android.enableAapt2
This property has no effect, AAPT2 is now always used.


WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableD8.desugaring=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'.


> Configure project :react-native-version-number
WARNING: The following project options are deprecated and have been removed: 
android.enableAapt2
This property has no effect, AAPT2 is now always used.


WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableD8.desugaring=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'.


> Configure project :react-native-webview
WARNING: The following project options are deprecated and have been removed: 
android.enableAapt2
This property has no effect, AAPT2 is now always used.


WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableD8.desugaring=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'.

:react-native-webview:reactNativeAndroidRoot /Users/mac/Documents/GitHub/myrn/node_modules/react-native/android

> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: /Users/mac/Documents/GitHub/myrn/android/app/google-services.json

> Task :app:installDebug
12:04:15 V/ddms: execute: running am get-config
12:04:15 V/ddms: execute 'am get-config' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
12:04:15 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Nexus_5X_API_28(AVD) - 9' for app:debug
12:04:15 D/app-debug.apk: Uploading app-debug.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
12:04:16 D/Device: Uploading file onto device 'emulator-5554'
12:04:16 D/ddms: Reading file permision of /Users/mac/Documents/GitHub/myrn/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk as: rw-r--r--
12:04:16 V/ddms: execute: running pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
12:04:16 V/ddms: execute 'pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
12:04:16 V/ddms: execute: returning
12:04:16 V/ddms: execute: running rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
12:04:16 V/ddms: execute 'rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
12:04:16 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installed on 1 device.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 5s
338 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 331 up-to-date
info Connecting to the development server...
info Starting the app on "emulator-5554"...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.dapppocket/.MainActivity }
```

Comment: you can try this `react-native link`

Answer (score 0):

Check if the current process is already up and running on any port

**STEP 1**

Run command-line as an Administrator. Then run the below mention command. type your port number in yourPortNumber

```
netstat -ano | findstr :yourPortNumber
```

it will list the processes and its PID (process identifier)

Then you execute this command after identifying the PID.

```
taskkill /PID typeyourPIDhere /F
```

**Note:**
Since taskkill is not working in some git bash command try:

```
tskill typeyourPIDhere
```

Run the first command again to check if the process is still available or not. You'll get an empty line if the process is successfully ended.

**STEP 2**

Sometimes similar problem are there on upgrading RN version. I haven't found the solution yet but realised that a clean in necessary before a successful build will occur.

Best solution for me so far is a batch script to start the project which includes gradlew clean

```
cd (path to project/android folder)

gradlew clean

cd (path to project root folder) 

react-native run-android
```

**Note:** all 4 commands can be combined together in the following way

```
cd (path to project/android folder) && gradlew clean && cd (path to project root folder) && react-native run-android
```

You're good to go

Hope this helps fix your problem.

Comment: thanks for your advise but it still not work, maybe I should try to init a new project above 0.60

Comment: you can delete `node modules` folder and do `npm install` again. and later do `react-native link`